# If all energy in the universe originally occupied the same point in space

Tags: entropy, quantum-entanglement

How can it not be entangled? What function of physics can allow everything that comes after to be completely separate? Do we have any known laws of physics that can make such a definition?

Thank you for considering.

Comment: We don't know how to use quantum mechanics to describe the very earliest moments of the universe. For that we would need a theory of quantum gravity and no such theory exists. Even if everything in the universe was initially entangled we would expect it to rapidly decohere as it expanded and the entanglement would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

[Look at the mainstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Theory) cosmological model, the Big Bang.

[image: bb]

Note that the model has changed and it no longer has a point singularity at the beginning , making it a fuzzy region expected to exist if gravity is quantized definitely. At the moment only effective quantum theories for gravitation  exist, and are used in cosmological models.

Entanglement requires one quantum mechanical function to describe the whole bubble in the beginning, and one has to wait for the definitive quantization of gravity.

In a sense, the quantum entanglement is already presupposed in the inflation model, assumed to start at  ~ $10^{-32}$ second after the fuzzy  beginning, because the model is used to explain the inhomogeneities of the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) .

It is after the first three minutes that one can start talking of decoherence and work with classical concepts of mass also.